# Custom VSTS Release task: Packaging and where is my icon

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to publish an extension for VSTS; a small release task. I'm not planning to publish this publicly, this is just for internal use. I've found quite a few "how to" posts, but they tend to be vague on some topics or even have outdated information. I did get my task out there and it works, but I still have some questions.

1) Packaging your extension:

According to [visualstudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task#step-3-package-your-extension) I need to package my extension into a .vsix file. Can someone explain to me what this does? I didn't do this step as it wasn't part of the first tutorial I found. My task is still up there and functional so I'm just not sure what the purpose of packaging is.

2) Icon questions

Trivial I know, but I can't seem to get my task icon to show up! I have an icon stored in the root of my folder I uploaded and I reference it in my extension manifest, but it won't seem to show up.

> "icons": {
>       "default": "icon.png"
>     },
>     "files": [
>       {
>         "path": "icon.png", "addressable": false
>       }
>     ]

Do I need to reference the icon in my task manifest somehow? I haven't seen any references of an icon property in the task.json. Additionally I have seen some sites saying the icon needs to be 32x32 png, but [Extension manifest reference](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/manifest#marketplace-discovery-properties) says it should be 128x128.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume you referred to [this](http://blog.devmatter.com/custom-build-tasks-in-vso/) tutorial, which is obsolete. You need to do with a vsix file that can be uploaded to VSTS.

Secondly, you need to put the icon.png file (32X32) to the root folder of the release task, then the icon file can be recognized. For example: the task’s files are in ReleaseTest folder, then the task.json and icon.png are in the root of ReleaseTest folder.

BTW, the 128X128 icon is used for the extension, you can check extensions on your marketplace site (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage/publishers/[publisher])

Comment: Thank you. I was able to package my extension and upload it using the marketplace. I see that my Icon was used manage extensions screen. However when I look for my custom task in the catalog it still shows the default "two gears on a page" icon. How do I set the icon for my task?

Comment: Hello. I was able to finally get my icon to update. It seemed like updating the extension was not enough, but I actually had to unshare and then re-share to get the task icon to update.

Comment: Hi @JustinHolbrook I have the same issue in tfs server 2018 update 2. what is the unshare re-share?